How to visualize attention for long sequences (e.g., amino acids of length 1000) in Transformer models?
I am working with Transformer models and I have a specific use case where I need to visualize the attention mechanism for long sequences. Specifically, I am dealing with amino acid sequences of length 1000 along with their related codons.
Given the length of these sequences, I'm finding it challenging to effectively visualize the attention weights. What are the best practices or techniques for visualizing attention in such long sequences?
Here are some specifics of my situation:

The sequence length is 1000.

I have multiple attention heads and possibly multiple layers.

I would like to visualize the attention weights in a way that is both informative and interpretable.


Key Questions:

What type of plot is best suited for visualizing attention weights in long sequences?

Are there any techniques to aggregate or simplify the attention visualization for long sequences?

Can interactive plots be beneficial for this purpose, and if so, which libraries or tools should I use?


What I Tried:
I have tried using heatmaps to visualize the attention weights, but with a sequence length of 1000, the plots become too dense and difficult to interpret. I have also considered aggregating the attention weights over smaller windows of tokens, which helps, but I'm looking for additional insights or best practices.
Expected Outcome:
I am looking for effective ways to visualize these attention weights so that the important patterns and relationships can be clearly seen, despite the long sequence length.
